# Query execution time in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm running queries in PL/SQL Developer. How to find out the running time of sql query in PL/SQL. I am querying specific tables. Like

```
select * from table_name where customer_id=1;

select * from movie_table where movie_id=8;
```

While i am using PL/SQL, i want to know the query running time.

Thanks, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your examples

Comment: Select sysdate from dual before and after each query.  Make sure you run each query twice if you want compile time removed from the equation.

Comment: Take a look at http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=2213

Comment: well it works on only count. It's not working on select * from table_name where customer_id=1; and it works only on select count (*) from table_name;

Comment: Good link.  I didn't know about that command that outputs the execution time.  While the link specifies sql plus, I just verified that it works in sql developer.  Hopefully @careem reads it.

Comment: What works only on count(*)?

Comment: This works only on count.

`declare
i number:=dbms_utility.get_time;
j number;
begin
select max(rownum) into j from table_work;
i:=round((dbms_utility.get_time-i)/100,2);
dbms_output.put_line(i || ' Sec');
end;`

Comment: If you read the entire page that @Hamidreza mentions you'll see a really simple way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, courtesy of @Hamidreza's link, is like this:

```
set timing on;
select * from table_name where customer_id=1;
```

The execution time will appear below the records selected.

Comment: Need to issue these SQL commands from Command Line window, not the SQL window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use dbms_utility.get_time function.

```
l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
select * from table_name where customer_id=1;
select * from movie_table where movie_id=8;
l_end := dbms_utility.get_time;
l_diff := (l_end-l_start)/100;
dbms_output.put_line('Overall Time: '|| l_diff);
```

Something like this, in brief.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried in SQL Window and didn't work.

Comment: Do you execute it on SQL Window and have added it to a PL/SQL function?

Comment: it does not work